# How to control C# string interpolation formatting for classes

Tags: c#

This works:

```cs
class Item
{
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Number.ToString();
}
```

then later:

```cs
var item = new Item() { Number = 12m };
Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item}");
```

prints

```
Item: 12
```

But what I really want to do instead is:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item:C2}");
```

And somehow get

```
Item: $12.00
```

Anyone know if/how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't specific to string interpolation as `Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item:C2}");` is the same as `Console.WriteLine("Item: {0:C2}", item);` is the same as `Console.WriteLine("Item: " + item.ToString("C2"));` (when such an overload is defined).  Also, if what you want is `item`'s `Number` formatted as currency then you can ask for that specifically: `Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item.Number:C2}");`

Comment: Right, I wanted to keep the code concise, and "Number" is really an implementation detail in my case that I wanted to hide. Making it public was the quickest way to explain the problem, but in real life, I want to be able to change the underlying backing scheme as needed.

Comment: Reference [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$"{item:C2}"` effectively calls `item.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`, so you can implement `IFormattable` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=net-6.0)):

```cs
class Item : IFormattable
{
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Number.ToString();

    // IFormattable's .ToString method:    
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) => Number.ToString(format, formatProvider);
}
```

Now this code will work:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item:C2}");
```

In this case it should work perfectly since you're basically proxying the same method on `decimal`, but if you're going to do anything more complicated, you should probably read the docs linked above, especially the  [Notes to Implementers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=net-6.0#notes-to-implementers) section.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed. Just couldn't figure out the right way to web search for it.